# How to open plain text file in KDevelop with embedded text editor

Tags: kdevelop

I cannot open some text files with an embedded text editor depending on the extension in the file name.

For example, if I have  `Wavefront .obj` file, KDevelop will open it with hex editor, in the `Open With` menu only hex editors are available.
There is `File Type Options` button in the file properties, but if I click to this button nothing happens and no output in stdout/stderr from KDevelop.

I am using `Gentoo Linux` distribution with `KDevelop 5.5.2`

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem, and here's quick solution:

1. Click right on your file in file manager (in my kde it's default dolphin);
2. Select "Properties";
3. In opened window click "File type options";
4. In the next opened window select "Embedding" tab;
5. In services prefering order list select Okteta, and then remove it;
6. Click ok and it's done.

KDevelop after that, stops use hex editor and open files in embedded text viewer. Note, that this recipe would work only for one file type (or extension), that was selected in first step.